# What kind of literary device is "the speed of light?" #idioms

Tags: idioms

He flew at the speed of light or the speed of sound.

Comment: It's a literal measure, not a literary device. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is the answer I'm looking for. I would call it a literal measure if I stated, "He drove at the speed of mom."

Comment: It's not a literary device until you use it in a literary way. "He flew at the speed of light or the speed of sound" could be a legitimate question on a test, and not a literary one.

Comment: Are you able to explain what is happening when I use it with the phrase, 'speed of mom'?

Comment: I think "the speed of mom" is idiosyncratic, but probably an attempt at humor—though whatever that joke might be would depend heavily on context and shared information.

Answer (score 1):

No one can actually fly (under normal conditions) at the speed of sound, let alone at the speed of light, so the sentence contains a hyperbole or exaggeration.

[Here](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-hyperboles.html) are some more examples.

Comment: I’m pretty sure pilots who’ve broken the sound barrier and exceeded Mach 1 speeds would disagree that no one can fly at the speed of sound, unless you’re referring only to self-propulsion (in which case no one, at least no one human, can fly at any speed at all).